# Windows 7 and ubuntu 12.04 dualboot

Tags: dual-boot, external-hdd

I have windows 7 on a partition of my harddisk and ubuntu 12.04 on a partition of a external HDD. Dual boot is working fine. Both systems are working fine.
Can I boot with my external HDD with my ubuntu ? ( ex: on another PC ? )
When i try to boot from the external HDD is not working ?
The only way i can boot ubuntu is from the normal boot menu choosing a option.
thanks

Answer (score 2):

Because when You installed Ubuntu on external drive You selected to install bootloader on harddisk.

My solution is: reinstall Ubuntu on external drive and make sure u select external drive when You select bootloader location(This is in partitioning tab).

Comment: Ok i reinstall it.from where i reinstall it ? From wubi or from live CD. wubi ask for bootloader ?